# Add prefix to the error message

Tags: 7, webforms, forms

How I can add some prefix to the all error messages?

Example:

```
This field is required!
```

and I need

```
Error: This field is required!
```

I'm using [Clientside Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/clientside_validation) module for error messages in my forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the output by implementing [theme_status_messages](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_statu%20s_messages/7) in your theme.

You could work from something like this. See $myprefix that I've added.

```
function MYTHEME_status_messages($variables) {
  $display = $variables ['display'];
  $output = '';

  $status_heading = array(
    'status' => t('Status message'),
    'error' => t('Error message'),
    'warning' => t('Warning message'),
  );
  foreach (drupal_get_messages($display) as $type => $messages) {
    $myprefix = $type == 'error' ? 'ERROR: ' : '';
    $output .= "<div class=\"messages $type\">\n";
    if (!empty($status_heading [$type])) {
      $output .= '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . $status_heading [$type] . "</h2>\n";
    }
    if (count($messages) > 1) {
      $output .= " <ul>\n";
      foreach ($messages as $message) {
        $output .= '  <li>' . $myprefix . $message . "</li>\n";
      }
      $output .= " </ul>\n";
    }
    else {
      $output .= $myprefix . reset($messages);
    }
    $output .= "</div>\n";
  }
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: It's working with Drupal default messages, but don't work with my messages in the webform, I'm using [Clientside Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/clientside_validation) module for this messages...